# How do i execute tail -f mylog.csv command for particular number of seconds for e.g. 60 seconds only

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, command

In order to execute tail -f mylog.log for particular number of seconds I have tried below way:
**$ (sleep 60s; tail -f mylog.csv) **

but problem in this command is it is not logging few events till 60s completes but i don't want this kind of behavior. I want to run  tail -f mylog.csv for 60 seconds and log whatever logs in 60 seconds time

Please help me in this.

I tried.

$ (sleep 60s; tail -f mylog.csv) -> not working.

also used below command

$ (timeout 60s; tail -f mylog.csv) -> not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
timeout 60s tail -f mylog.csv > output.log
```

*It works as i checked on one of my RHEL7 server.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `timeout` installed, you can do

```
(tail -f mylog.csv & sleep 60; kill $! $BASHPID)
```